# Moving a docker-compose container to openshift V3

Tags: openshift, gitlab

I would like to move the Omnibus gitlab docker image to openshift V3,
so I've got the dockerfile and docker-compose files @ https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/tree/master/docker. 
What is the best way for having a scalable openshift v3 pod ? 
As the command oc import docker-compose is experimental so I stuck and lost in the process of building a reliable solution.
Thanks
Herve

Answer (score 9):

You should use https://kompose.io/

Run `kompose convert --provider=openshift` in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yaml` file.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, that capability was introduced in openshift origin : https://github.com/openshift/origin/commit/7a08be6b6e61cef531e8a6d99df60e50fca87221

```
oc import docker-compose -f [docker-compose-file.yml]
```

**Note:** I haven't tested it yet. I hope it works.

Comment: This is no longer available - it was removed in favour of using Kompose according to the discussion here https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/16748#issuecomment-335119762